# SQL Count using two people

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I'm trying to figure out from the past two days how to perform an count function on the following query: For each module, list the module title and the number of activities scheduled for the module. 
My two tables that are needed for this are :
TblActivity - ID,  Name, Type, ModuleID,  Day, Time, RoomID. 
TblModule - ID, Title
I'm sure GROUP BY needs to be used as well but I don't know how to implement it. I'm using SQL server management studio 2008. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables on the `ID` column, group by the `Title` column, and then select the `Title` column and the number of matched activities (`COUNT(TblActivity.ID)`).

```
SELECT Title, COUNT(TblActivity.ID)
FROM TblModule
JOIN TblActivity ON TblActivity.ID=TblModule.ID
GROUP BY Title
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This works great. I can now see how you did this. Will definitely help in the future queries!

Comment: @AdrianGrzymala - If this answer solves your problem then you need to mark it as answer by selecting the **tickmark** to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following query.

```
SELECT  
    TblModule.ID,  
    TblModule.Title,
    COUNT (TblActivity.ID) AS ActivityCount
FROM
    TblModule
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TblActivity
       ON TblActivity.ModuleID = TblModule.ID
GROUP BY
    TblModule.ID,  
    TblModule.Title
```

For every module it joins corresponding activities and counts them for each of the modules using grouping.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT M.Title, COUNT (A.ModuleID) AS NUMBER_OF_ACTIVITIES
 FROM TblModule M
 LEFT JOIN TblActivity A
 ON M.ID = A.ModuleID
 GROUP BY Title
```